# selectManyMenu custom filter primefaces

Tags: primefaces, filter

I'm trying to customize the filter of a selectManyMenu in primefaces. I am using filterMatchMode="custom" and filterFunction="filterByName" :

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{searchBean.searchCriteria.ingredients}" label="Select ingredients" showCheckbox="true" style="width:350px;"filter="true" id="ingredientSelectMenu" filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction="filterByName" >
```

and my script :

```
<script>
    function filterByName(itemLabel, filterValue){ 
        alert("aaaaaaaaa");
}   
</script>
```

But it doesn't enter on my alert.

Comment: 1. return true after the alert. 2. give space before filter="true" 3. Open firebug or IE advanced options and do script debugging. See what error you get in console.

Comment: I get the same error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: filterByName is not defined"...

Comment: Then it is not able to see the function. Try adding function  in head and playing with arguments and return value of function too.